# Using two reference values for a scalar variable: What's the name of this type of problem?

Tags: constrained-optimization, interpolation, optimal-control, extrapolation, distance-measure

I don't really know where to ask this one...
In fact, I am not sure I can define it properly.

Here goes...

Let's say I take measurements.

In order to "normalize" these measurements, I divide their values by a reference measurement.

So, if my reference measurement has value `100`, and one measurement has value `150`, I rescale it as follows: `150 / 100 = 1.5`. That particular measurement's value is `1.5` time the reference value.

So far, trivial.

Now, time for a picture:

[image]

The triangles are measurement values. `A` and `B` are reference values.

The domain the measurements are taken in indicates that the closer a measurement value is to `A`, the more `A` should be the reference value to rescale it. Similarly, the closer a measurement value is to `B`, the more B should be the reference value to rescale it.

So, values `1` and `2` should be restated in terms of `A`, while values `4` and `5` should be restated in terms of `B`.

But, in general, all values should probably be restated in function of `A` *and* `B`. This is particular true for value `3` in the picture, as it is almost equidistant from `A` and `B`.

In other words, there must be a function `f(x){A, B}`, that will allow to order all measurements.

What do you call that type of problem? Any reference or pointer I could use to restate what I mean?

--

Update 1:

Here is a metaphor that just came to me...
Let's say I must define a scale that measure the total cost of moving an object at a certain speed.

`A` and `B` become two reference "cost per unit of speed"s. For speeds close to `B`, the total cost can be accurately estimated in terms of `B`. For speeds close to `A`, the total cost can be accurately estimated in terms of `A`.
For speeds in between `A` and `B`, the total cost must be a function of `A` and `B`.

The farther away a speed is from `A`/`B`, the less `A`/`B` is a factor in the cost of moving the object at that speed.

Comment: I think that you can just interpolate your reference measurement, and use the interpolated values to normalize the other measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought of *barycentric coordinates*? There is a unique way to write $x=\alpha A + \beta B$ with $\alpha+\beta=1$.

Barycentric coordinates are usually employer in larger dimensions, but seem to be the concept you are looking for. You can sort your observations according to either $\alpha$ or $\beta$, this will give you their "closeness" to either. If $A$ and $B$ are well chosen, values should cluster around $[0,1]$, or even around $\{0,1\}$. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system